# Rendering Raw HTML data from a dynamically populated Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a complex Json data coming as a string being part of Model.

On Document ready I am parsing some JSON into a Javascript object with the help of following code:

```
    JSON.parse($('#myData').val());
```

I am evaluating some condition in the JS function & getting a raw HTML string (something like : `<h2><strong>Note :</strong> No Data found for the selection made</h2>` )

I want to make the div visible & plugin this code in @Html.Raw() that is present in my HTML body after the above statement gets evaluated.

For example:

```
<div id="divNoDataFoundMessage" style="display: none">
     <span class="" style="padding-right: 100px;">
      @{ 
           @Html.Raw()
       }
    </span>
 </div>
```

Please help me how I can substitute the data from document.ready to the above code to display it dynamically.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.MyListData"  id="myData"/>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse($('#myData').val());

        if (jsonData.NoDriversFound != "") {
            $("#divNoDataFoundMessage").show();
            $("#divNoDataFoundMessage span").text(jsonData.NoDriversFound);
        }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, what's @{ @Html.Raw() )?  Is this some kind of delimeter/tag that you want swapping out for a message?  Or, is this MVC/Razor helper code you're running on the server?  Your js looks ok, providing your if condition is true and your div (with id) exists in the DOM.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing.  You're dealing with some jQuery/Javascript on the client in `$(document).ready()` but also talking about server-side Razor markup like: `@{ @Html.Raw() }`  I think your question might be made more clear if you tell us where the JSON data in `myData` is intended to come from.  Looks like it is expected as soon as the page is ready.

Comment: To make my question clear, I am just trying to render <h2><strong>Note :</strong> No Data found for the selection made</h2> in a div, after the page gets loaded completely. But upon doing this the html tags are appearing as it is, instead of getting rendered. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Place Html Dynamicaly inside div try as follows:

```
$("#divID").html(JSON.parse($('#myData').val()));
```

Comment: No luck. HTML tags are still not getting rendered.

Comment: Some other problem was forcing to throw the exception in jquery code, once that rectified, it started working. :)